# Motorola Datawedge не работает с буфером обмена

Tags: кодировка, windows-ce

Привет всем. Есть девайс (Терминал Сбора Данных) Motorola MC3000c50. Есть написанная программа для ТСД, которая принимает сканированные штрих-коды через буфер обмена WinCE. 
Установил на ТСД Motorola Datawedge, но есть два но:

1. На самом терминале Datawedge отображается криво (из трея если вызвать, показываются не буквы, а кракозябры),
2. При настройке через комп: ставлю output - clipboard - но чтения не происходит.

Проверить буфер обмена через какой-нибудь блокнот не могу: стоит WinCE 5.0 Core, без Notepad или каких-либо ещё программ с Copy-Paste. Пробовал установить Notepad для WinCE, но работоспособного на платформе пока не нашел.

Буду рад любым наводкам, заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первое вылечилось заменой терминала на цветой, с Windows CE Pro. Datawedge на нем заработал отлично.
Второе побеждается настройкой Route в Advanced Configuration. Видимо раньше она мне на глаза не попадалась.